# performance of member variable access with 'this->'

Tags: c++

i just had a heated discussion with my cpp tutor about member variable access with this `this->` vs 'just the name'.

```
class Test{
  int a;
  int data[50000000];
  int b;

  Test(int c,int d){
    a=c; //or this->a=c;
    b=d; //or this->b=d;
  }
};
```

his understanding is, that the plain name implies a reference to the member variable, while using `this->` expands to `(*this).`, the latter of which I agree to.
For performance reasons, you would use a reference to the variable, because the pointer deferencing copies the whole object into place, before accessing just a part. since this happens on ever `this->`, this would have quite a bad impact on performance.

But I have tried both versions, translated to assembly, and there is no difference. why is that? (I am not used to assembly enough to understand the whole context, so I have no idea)

Is the compiler not using references, and instead using something more akind to the dereferencing, or is the dereferencing simply not doing what I expect it to do, in this context? (we have been talking about c++11, if that matters)

Comment: With "just the name", the dereference of `this` is implied. If you compare the generated machine code you would not see any difference. Accessing a (non-static) member variable is *always* done through the object.

Comment: I'm almost sure that a or this->a is exactly the same when you are in a member function.

Comment: *"the pointer derferencing copies the whole object into place"* - pointer dereferencing does not copy anything.

Comment: _syntactic sugar_ does not have consequences on performances ^^

Comment: thank to `int data[50000000];` the program probably cannot run and the performance issue is not the issue ^^

Comment: @bruno that's only ~400Mb, plenty of room on a modern computer for that. Might not fit in the default place for automatic storage duration objects.

Comment: @Caleth I was thinking about a local var of type _Test_, too large for the default stack size

Comment: It sounds like both you and your tutor are labouring under the misconception that there is a one-to-one correspondence between source code and machine code.

Comment: "because the pointer deferencing copies the whole object ". Think about it - where would it copy the object _to_ ? `this` is the location where the object lives, so if you copied it elsewhere then `this` would need to change. Now imagine `this->c = this->a + this->b;`. How could this possibly work with copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a member inside a non-static member function with and without `this->` results in the same machine code. The latter is syntactic sugar for the former. The code

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    A() {
        a = 1;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    int b;
    B() {
        this->b = 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

is translated without optimization to

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 8]
        call    A::A() [base object constructor]
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 16]
        call    B::B() [base object constructor]
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
A::A() [base object constructor]:                              # @A::A() [base object constructor]
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     dword ptr [rax], 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
B::B() [base object constructor]:                              # @B::B() [base object constructor]
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     dword ptr [rax], 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Dereferencing a pointer does not copy the object but yields a reference to the object. Otherwise code like

```
int a(0);
int pa = &a;
*pa = 12;
std::cout << a << '\n'; // prints 12
```

would not work as expected. Also this access is by reference:

```
class A {
public:
    int a(0);
    int b(0);
    int c(0);
    A() {
        a = 1;
        this->b = 2;
        (*this).c = 3;
        std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << '\n'; // prints 1 2 3
    }
};
```

If it was a copy you could not set the value of the member variables. Every time you can change the value of the origin, it is a reference and not a copy.